# Nodejs waiting for 127.0.0.1:9229 to be free

Tags: node.js

When I try to use `debugger` in node to open debugger, I get an error 'Timeout (2000) waiting for 127.0.0.1:9229 to be free'. How can I resolve this and run the debugger correctly ?

```
function foo() {
    var a = 5;
    debugger
    console.log(a)
}

foo()
```

I have already tried changing the port using `node inspect --port=9230 app.js` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `node --inspect-brk app.js`

Comment: I have tried it as well. Still don't work.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
node --inspect-brk app.js
```

replace `app.js` with your file name that you want to run, and you can insert your additional command alongside with this line.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, it took me hours to figure it out...

Run the following command:

```
node inspect --port=9228 file.js
```

Comment: WOW, this worked and saved me a ton of time. Why does `9228` work? I'm running from inside a docker container by the way

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue by using VS Code. VS code document helps. Replace program.js with your js file name.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

> if the program should not start running but must wait for the debugger to attach:
>
> `node --inspect-brk program.js`

Answer (score 1):

Use `node --inspect-brk {js file name}` instead. It will work.

--inspect-brk=[host:port]

1. Enable inspector agent
   2.Bind to address or hostname host (default:127.0.0.1)
   3.Listen on port port (default: 9229)
   4.Break before user code starts

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the command you give to node, it should be node --inspect..

You are missing the -- in front of inspect :)

Answer (score -1):

Install

npm install --global node-inspect

Then
node-inspect script.js

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspect